# Self-Employment: is equipment deductible as part of the home office deduction, or as a separate deduction?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, tax-deduction, self-employment, home-office

I have a side gig and am setting up a separate home office area for exclusive side-gig use.  I intend to take the home office deduction, but am not yet decided if I'll calculate it the simplified way ($5/sq. ft.) or the more complex way.  In determining this, I need some clarity: is equipment purchased for exclusive use in the side gig and primarily in the home office, only deductible as part of the home office deduction?  Or can it be its own separate business expense deduction?

In other words, *if I use the simplified method for calculating the home office deduction, can I still deduct the cost of the equipment separately?*  Also, does it depend on the specific equipment?  E.g. are hardware and furniture generally treated differently?

**Details**

My side gig is web development.

Equipment under consideration to purchase:

- laptop
- desk
- Ethernet cables
- Wifi extender
- Rug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every separate item is deducted separately using its own depreciation schedule (or in case of small items as a misc expense or office supplies).

Comment: when you say "its own depreciation schedule", does that include the option to deduct the entire expense outright in the first year?

Comment: @JamesDunn if there's such an option then yes.